# React Router + Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iAG6h9ff5s) and I am wondering how do you use it with redux?

My render right now

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

router render example from tutorial

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Featured}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="archives(/:article)" name="archives" component={Archives}></Route>
      <Route path="settings" name="settings" component={Settings}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
app);
```

I am not sure how Provider fits into the mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `Provider` is just a wrapper component that wraps the rest of your application, so it should surround your root component no matter what that might be. In the example you described above, `Router` would be considered the root component in your application. i.e.

```
ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Featured}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="archives(/:article)" name="archives" component={Archives}></Route>
        <Route path="settings" name="settings" component={Settings}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Though, most people will break their routes into a seperate file, so it might look more like this..

routes.js

```
// imports

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute component={Featured}
    <Route path="archives(/:article)" name="archives" component={Archives} />
    <Route path="settings" name="settings" component={Settings}></Route>
  </Route>
)
```

index.js

```
// imports
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>{routes}</Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

After further review, it looks like you don't have to wrap `routes` in the `Router`component, you can simply do: `<Router history={hashHistory} routes={routes} />` Just thought that was a nice enhancement!

Comment: Yes this has helped. I am trying it now but I have alot of buttons on my site that trigger "modals" and it seems like link router is thinking they are routes and sending me back to my home page. How do I stop this?

Comment: That's interesting, I'd need more information to properly figure out what's going on in this instance, but it sounds like the buttons that you are using are triggering some sort of event, you should be able to prevent this by using `event.preventDefault` in your click handler for those buttons, but again, would need more info to say for sure :)